# String.Encoding is not getting translated to NSStringEncoding in swift 3 to objective C conversion

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

Am converting my existing swift source code base to swift 3 and have a method in a swift class which was earlier returning NSStringEncoding. In swift 3, the compiler asks me to convert NSStringEncoding to String.Encoding. But this method is now not getting reflected in the objective-c's generated interface and now am not able to call this method in my objective-c classes.

This is a sample code snippet :

```
@objc
open class MyClass: NSObject{
    open var textEncoding: String.Encoding { get { return self.getEncoding() } }

    fileprivate func getEncoding() -> String.Encoding{
        // some conversion code
        return encoding
    }
}
```

In an objective-c class,

```
-(void)demoFunc:(MyClass * _Nonnull)response{
(i)  NSStringEncoding responseEncoding = response.textEncoding;
}
```

The compiler is throwing this error for the above line,

> Property 'textEncoding' not found on object of type 'MyClass
>   *'

How do I fix this issue as I cannot declare/use NSStringEncoding in swift file and in Objective C I cannot use String.Encoding ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foundation defines

```
typedef NSUInteger NSStringEncoding;
NS_ENUM(NSStringEncoding) {
    NSASCIIStringEncoding = 1,      /* 0..127 only */
    // ...
};
```

which is mapped to Swift as

```
extension String {
    public struct Encoding : RawRepresentable {
        public var rawValue: UInt
        // ...
    }
}
```

So what you can do is to pass the raw value back to Objective-C:

```
open var textEncoding: UInt { return self.getEncoding().rawValue }
```